# Date not parsing correct in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm using timestamp that is inserted into my PostreSQL database & trying to parse it to become user friendly, however I'm getting the wrong year?

```
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
   return datum/1000;
}
let timestamp = toTimestamp('Sun Jan 19 2020 21:19:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)');

var d = new Date();
d.setTime(timestamp);

console.log(d.toGMTString()); //Mon, 19 Jan 1970 06:44:28 GMT
```

I'm expecting a result of `Sun, 19 Jan 2020 21:19:40 GMT`

Comment: Consider `var d = new Date(timestamp)` (once you stop dividing by 1000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't divide datum by 1000

see here

```js
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
   return datum;
}
let timestamp = toTimestamp('Sun Jan 19 2020 21:19:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)');

var d = new Date();
d.setTime(timestamp);

console.log(d.toGMTString()); // Sun, 19 Jan 2020 21:19:40 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a unit of measurement error. Date expects epoch in milliseconds but you are dividing the datum variable by 1000, turning it into seconds. This is resulting in the discrepancy and can be fixed by removing the divide by 1000 step.

toTimestamp then becomes:

```
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   return Date.parse(strDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use only `datum` instead of `datum/1000` except this your code is working fine

```js
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
   return datum;
   //return Date.parse(strDate);
}
let timestamp = toTimestamp('Sun Jan 19 2020 21:19:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)');

var d = new Date();
d.setTime(timestamp);

console.log(d.toGMTString()); //Mon, 19 Jan 1970 06:44:28 GMT
```